# How to make \cdot operator same width as / (division slash) operator and vice versa

Tags: horizontal-alignment, math-operators, width

This is the code I use:

```
\begin{aligned}
&a\cdot{}a\\
&a/a
\end{aligned}
```

this is the output I get (red line is to emphasize unequal alignment):

[image]

How can I make cdot's and slash's widths match?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use a `\makebox` to create a box as wide as the slash:

[image]

### Code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{calc}

\newcommand*{\mycdot}{\makebox[\widthof{/}]{$\cdot$}}
\newcommand*{\myslash}{\makebox[\widthof{${}\cdot{}$}]{{}/{}}}

\begin{document}\noindent
\verb|\cdot| same width as slash:
\begin{align*}
x &= a \mycdot a \\
x &= a / a
\end{align*}
Slash same width as \verb|\cdot|:
\begin{align*}
x &= a \cdot a \\
x &= a \myslash a
\end{align*}
\end{document}
```

Comment: You can get it to work across all math styles with `\usepackage{scalerel}
\newcommand*{\mycdot}{\ThisStyle{\makebox[\widthof{$\SavedStyle/$}]{$\SavedStyle\cdot$}}}`

Comment: @bp2017: Please correct the title of the question. Both options are now provided.

Answer (score 7):

This scales in subscripts and superscripts and allows for different widths based on other operators.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\makeatletter
\newcommand\wslash[1][\cdot]{\mathbin{\mathpalette\w@slash{#1}}}
\newcommand\w@slash[2]{%
  \settowidth\dimen@{$\m@th#1#2$}%
  \makebox[\dimen@]{$\m@th#1/$}%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{align}
&a\cdot a\\
&a\wslash a \\
&a+a\\
&a\wslash[+]a\\
&x_{a\cdot a}\\
&x_{a\wslash a}
\end{align}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: @bp2017 I'm not sure what you're referring to.